# Построение диаграмм Венна

Tags: svg, javascript, визуализация

Здравствуйте!

Есть множество статей (~100..150), каждой сопоставлен список тегов. Нужно построить визуализацию кругами Эйлера (диаграмма Венна). Скажите, чем потенциально такое можно реализовать, есть ли какие-то алгоритмы, что почитать на эту тему.

Усложненный вариант: элементы (статьи) закреплены по вертикели: на шкале отражен возраст читателей статьи, сам элемент выглядит как вертикальной отрезок.

P. S.: планирую рисовать в svg используя d3.js

---

На данный момент идеи такие:

Разбить все поле на клетки и ставить элементы только в их узлах.

Далее расставить центры кругов (которые и не круги будут) исходя из количества элементов и близости других кругов с общими элементами. Центры кругов будут располагаться на одной линии, так как элементы находятся на фиксированной высоте.

Далее расположить элементы в зависимости от центров их зон. При этом в одном «столбце» — один элемент.

После чего для каждой группы элементов по узлам клеток провести линии от того, что ближе к центру группы до всех остальных (каким-нибудь алгоритмом поиска пути в графе). Цена узлов зависит от того, что через этот узел уже проходит.

Фактически задача сводится к упорядочиванию массива статей и построению зон между ними. Скорее всего будет работать долго, но можно выводить результат «на лету», строя элемент и зону сразу после того, как его/ее положение высчитано.

Comment: Почему вы хотите использовать диаграммы Венна? Все известные мне модели доходят до шести-восьми множеств, а у вас их 100-150. Может быть стоит рассмотреть другие способны визуализации?

Comment: 100-150 — это элементов, а тегов гораздо меньше.

В любом случае, что посоветуете? На самом деле задаче несколько сложнее, так как некоторые статьи еще и в циклы связаны, но это учитывать не обязательно.

В общем должно быть удобно находить материал на пересечениях кругов.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, у вас получится 100-150 перекрывающихся кругов. Вы уверены, что там что-то будет видно? Может быть использовать визуализации двудольных графов?

Comment: Нет, у меня 150 статей и 20 тегов. Соответственно будет 20 кругов и 150 элементов.

Двудольные графы — не информативно на таких больших множиствах, будет слишком много линий. Впрочем, стоит попробовать. Есть несколько идей.